# Why does Stackoverflow occur in CPython

Tags: python, memory-management, cpython

Currently python has a recursion depth of 1000 but i am failing to understand why there is a limit since everything in located on the heap.

> Memory management in Python involves a private heap containing all
>   Python objects and data structures. The management of this private
>   heap is ensured internally by the Python memory manager

A common way to avoid stackoverflow is to declare your own stack and use a loop but in this case we are already using the heap.Is it a restriction set by python memory management? .

Comment: Python has a *configurable* recursion *exception* limit. It is a reminder that there is most likely something going wrong. And of cause that you should prevent recursion if possible. (It always is.)

Comment: "everything is allocated on the heap" is wrong. In CPython, `Frame` objects are allocated on the heap, but recursive calls generally work by recursively calling the `ceval` function with the main interpreter loop. So, unrestricted recursion could lead to a C-level stack overflow, which would be bad. Removing that is what [Stackless](https://github.com/stackless-dev/stackless/wiki) is all about (although it's not as exciting since `greenlets` and then Python 3.3 itself found ways to do coroutines without changing the core interpreter loop).

Comment: But even Stackless lets you set a maximum recursion depth, because when you write an unbounded-recursive function, it's nicer to get a `RecursionError` after a couple seconds than to drive your system into swap hell so everything (not just your program) slows to a crawl and takes minutes to recover after you finally get a `MemoryError`.

Comment: In a language that encouraged recursion whenever possible, like Scheme, this wouldn't be a good heuristic. But in a language that discourages recursion whenever it's not necessary, like Python, it usually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CPython` is implemented in C, and while Python's data is allocated from a heap, layers of native C function calls in the implementation necessarily use the platform C's stack.  So, for example, recursive calls of depth `R` in Python code also lead, at runtime, to calls to C functions of depth at least `R` in the C implementation.

So it's not primarily about the data, but about the call-stack depth.  It's possible to implement Python in C in ways that don't so directly rely on the platform C's call stack.  For example, see the "[Stackless Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackless_Python)" experiment.  That's trickier, though, and it's unlikely the core CPython implementation will ever adopt that kind of approach.

Comment: Clear and simple to understand even to a beginner programmer like me.Its great to have you on SO and yes timsort is awesome.